# How to get the parent element name of a child element in JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some dynamic JSON where I won't know the full structure before processing.

However, I do know the JSON may contain certain nested elements of interest.

e. for this sample payload

```
{
  "id": "3334343",
  "contractor": {
    "ppsNo": "123334"
  },
  "fullTimeStaff":{
    "ppsNo": "343434"
  }
}
```

I would like to find the name of all the outer elements that contain an element named **ppsNo**.

I have tried using **root.findParents("ppsNo")** but that gives me the ppsNo elements rather than the outer(parent) elements of **contractor** and **fullTimeStaff** that im interested in.

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String payload = "{\n" +
            "  \"id\": \"3334343\",\n" +
            "  \"contractor\": {\n" +
            "    \"ppsNo\": \"123334\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"fullTimeStaff\":{\n" +
            "    \"ppsNo\": \"123334\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

    JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(payload);

    List<JsonNode> nodes = root.findParents("ppsNo");
```

The JsonNodes returned are the `{"ppsNo":"123334"}` elements rather than the outer containing nodes ("contractor" and "fullTimeStaff").

Is there a way to do this? I had looked at using JSON path but i couldn't see an obvious way to get the real parent (containing/outer)  element using that as well.

I'm using Jackson in this example but im open to alternatives

Comment: Related: [How to find parent Json node while parsing a JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20881154/1371329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option with the JsonPath library that **returns the entire matched paths** instead of the values. Thus you can do something like:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();
List<String> pathList = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(payload).read("$..ppsNo");

/* Returns :
 * [
 *   "$['contractor']['ppsNo']",
 *   "$['fullTimeStaff']['ppsNo']"
 * ]
 */
```

You just have to parse the result to the correct type, and remove the last element to get the direct parent.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\$\\[)(\\w+)(?!\\])");
pathList = pathList.stream().map(path -> {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(path.toString());
    return m.find() ? m.group(0) : null;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(pathList); // [contractor, fullTimeStaff]
```

Here is the link to the official [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) Maven repository.

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for. How I extract the field name from  ```/* Returns :
 * [
 *   "$['contractor']['ppsNo']",
 *   "$['fullTimeStaff']['ppsNo']"
 * ]
 */```

Comment: My first guess to extract it would be to substring each element from the list... But it may exists a better solution!

Comment: Yeah would like to think there's a better way than having parse each element in the list to remove the "$['" and "']"....but an easier way of doing it looking at https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath isn't obvious to me

Comment: @Kapcash Added a second part to your response.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks, of course using regex is also a solution :) But you could use regex to solve the main problem directly. Don't know what's better.

Comment: Better to parse the nodes, then use an expression on a string value. I would not recommend regex for the parsing, but your original result was returning string values...

Comment: Like the Json path approach for the most path. But prefer to avoid using the regex for getting the node names from pathList if possible

Answer (score 0):

i didn't put a lot of time to write the code.

the expression you are looking for in `Regex` is `\{\n    "ppsNo": "\w+"\n  }` ( you test it using link https://regex101.com ). what you should do is when you encounter this expression start coming backward and read the first word in " ". i hope it helped you

Comment: Yes I would prefer to avoid using string or regex style solutions if possible. Is there any library or clever way we parse this JSON in Java to achieve this? Open to using any libs

Answer (score 0):

We can use recursion to search for the target parent nodes with the help of [JsonNode.fields](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()) method as following example.

```
public class GetParentByChildName {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String payload = "{                                      \n"
                + "  \"id\": \"3334343\",                        \n"
                + "  \"contractor\": {                           \n"
                + "    \"ppsNo\": \"123334\"                     \n"
                + "  },                                          \n"
                + " \"arr\": [                                   \n"
                + "    {                                         \n"
                + "      \"contractor2\": {                      \n"
                + "        \"ppsNo\": \"123334\"                 \n"
                + "      }                                       \n"
                + "    },                                        \n"
                + "    [                                         \n"
                + "      {                                       \n"
                + "        \"contractor3\": {                    \n"
                + "          \"ppsNo\": \"123334\"               \n"
                + "        }                                     \n"
                + "      }                                       \n"
                + "    ]                                         \n"
                + "  ],                                          \n"
                + "  \"fullTimeStaff\":{                         \n"
                + "    \"ppsNo\": \"123334\"                     \n"
                + "  }                                           \n"
                + "}                                               ";

        JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(payload);
        List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        getParentName(root, "ppsNo", fieldNames);
        System.out.println(fieldNames);
    }

    private static void getParentName(JsonNode node, String targetChildName, List<String> fieldNames) {
        if (node.getNodeType() == JsonNodeType.ARRAY) {
            node.elements().forEachRemaining(x -> getParentName(x, targetChildName, fieldNames));
            return;
        }
        if (node.getNodeType() != JsonNodeType.OBJECT) {
            return;
        }
        node.fields().forEachRemaining(x -> {
            Iterator<String> iter = x.getValue().fieldNames();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String fieldName = iter.next();
                if (fieldName.equals(targetChildName)) {
                    fieldNames.add(x.getKey());
                }
            }
            getParentName(x.getValue(), targetChildName, fieldNames);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this approach looks promising...think it will work for the example we have here but wondering would it be able a scenario where we had nested arrays in one of the elements which had more objects with the field name we are looking for?

Comment: @user805703 check if the updated answer can handle your scenario.